# How to change color of well log using Ocean based on different depths?

Tags: c#, ocean, petrel

I have created a new well log attribute and based on standard deviation I want to give it different color at different depths.

The new well log created is opened in a new well section template and I am unable to access that new template as well with Ocean.

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand your question.

What you describe might be a DictionaryWellLog.

A dictionary well log will have discrete values and is displayed as solid blocks of different colors. The colors can be chosen by editing the ColorTable for the the log.

If you are trying to actually color a normal WellLog and change the Color of the curve with the depth, you may need to implement your own custom WellSectionVisual and related classes.

You can check the Circle sample of the SDK as it includes a custom track and visual for the well section window.

Comment: Thanks for your input and I had actually read the Circle Sample after putting up my question and after a few modifications it is working now.